# Return elements of requested type from function in typescript

Tags: generics, typescript

In my code sample i want to search for all components of a given type and want them returned in an array (E.g. search for all components of type A in components[]). But i receive the errors for the marked lines as below the code sample.

```
class Component{/*...*/};

class A extends Component { /*...*/}

class B extends Component {/*...*/}

class Entity {
    public components: Component[];

    getComponentsByType<T>(): Array<T> {
        let returnValue: Array<T> = [];

        for (let component of this.components) {
            if (component instanceof T) {  // <-- 1. Error
                returnValue.push(<T>component); // <-- 2. Error
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

1. Error: `[ts] Cannot find name 'T'.`
2. Error: `[ts] Neither type 'Component' nor type 'T' is assingable to the other.`

What did i do wrong here? (Is this even possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally feasible. You need to pass the class name as parameter. Check this out. [Using Class Types in Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics). And `getComponentsByType<T>` should be replaced with `getComponentsByType<T extends Component>`  .

```
class Component {/*...*/ };

class A extends Component { field = 'A'; }

class B extends Component { field = 'B'; }

class Entity {
    public components: Component[];

    getComponentsByType<T>(t: { new (): T }): Array<T> {
        let returnValue: Array<T> = [];

        for (let component of this.components) {
            if (component instanceof t) {  
                returnValue.push(<T>component); 
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}

let e = new Entity();
e.components = [new A(), new A(), new B()];
console.log(e.getComponentsByType(A));
```